# Create a list of objects in acrobat using javascript not same as regular javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I am trying to create a list of objects using javascript for an acrobat form. But the usual javascript code used does not work.
This is the code that I am using:

```
function updatePage1(totalRows)
{
    var B = [];

    var totalRows = 25;
    for(var i = 1; i <= 1; ++i)
    {
        app.alert(i);
        app.alert(this.getField("CostHead"+i.toString()).value);
        var costhead = this.getField("CostHead"+i.toString()).value;
        B.push({
            1 : { cost : 0.00, val: costhead }
        });

    }

    var valu = B[1].cost;
    app.alert(valu);
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this... If you MUST use the row number as the key and you have an array of objects, you're going to need to change the row number to a string.

```
function updatePage1(totalRows)
{
    var B = [];

    var totalRows = 25;
    for(var i = 1; i <= 1; ++i)
    {
        app.alert(i);
        app.alert(this.getField("CostHead"+i.toString()).value);
        var costhead = this.getField("CostHead"+i.toString()).value;
        B.push({
            "1" : { cost : 0.00, val: costhead }
        });

    }

    var valu = B["1"].cost;
    app.alert(valu);
}
```

But a better fix is to ditch the row number altogether and just rely on the array order to get the object you need. Start your increment at 0.

```
function updatePage1(totalRows)
{
    var B = [];
    var totalRows = 25;
    for(var i = 0; i < totalRows; ++i)
    {
        app.alert(i);
        app.alert(this.getField("CostHead")+(i+1).toString()).value);
        var costhead = this.getField("CostHead"+(i+1).toString()).value;
        B.push({ cost : 0.00, val: costhead });
        var valu = B[i].cost;
        app.alert(valu);
    }
}
```